# Google script to insert current date only once in cell when specific values are selected in the same row, different cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a script that is giving me trouble. Column G has picklist values M1, M2,M3,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,C1,C2,C3. I would like to have a timestamp inserted in column t when any of the S-values (S1,S2,S3,S4,S5) are selected from the picklist. I would like this done on the first occurrence only, not when the picklist value in column g is subsequently updated or changed.

I'm close, but the current script updates the date in the entire column t.

I'd also like to clean up line 9 if possible.

I have this so far:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('ClientList');
  var stageValues = s.getRange('g3:g').getValues();
  var dateValues = s.getRange('t3:t').getValues();

  for (var row in stageValues) 
    for (var col in stageValues[row])
      if (stageValues[row][col] == 'S1' || stageValues[row][col] == 'S2' || stageValues[row][col] == 'S3' || stageValues[row][col] == 'S4' || stageValues[row][col] == 'S5' && dateValues[row][col] == '') {
        num = parseInt(row) + 3;
        s.getRange('t' + num).setValue(new Date());
        }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say picklist values, i'm assuming you mean a dropdown list.  But regardless this will work.  When ever a cell is manually edited in column G the onEdit trigger will check for an "S" value and the time stamp in column T.  If no time stamp is found it will place a new time stamp.  "e" is the trigger object containing information about the cell that was edited.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "ClientList" ) {
      if( e.range.getColumn() === 7 ) {  // edit in column G
        if( e.value.charAt(0) === "S" ) {
          if( e.range.offset(0,13,1,1).getValue() === "" ) {  // no value in T
            e.range.offset(0,13,1,1).setValue(new Date());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: TheWizEd - thanks a ton for the help. It makes total sense and works like a charm. Thank you!